# ADF - The error handling activity is not being executed after a failed activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

In ADF, when an activity is failed, I want it to execute an activity which logs the error. However, in my pipeline, the error handling activity is not processed after a failed activity. What is the issue with this? I have included the screenshot of my pipeline below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Adf, the flow signifies the AND operator.
Meaning the error handling activity would run only if all activities associated to it would fail and that is never possible since the activities are in sequential success mode.
Please follow my blog for your understanding and resolution
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/